# Generate HTML from file fetched from server

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am currently working on a dynamic website project (I'm not new to coding in general but web development is something I had to learn from scratch). After getting familiar with Angular CLI and Bootstrap I find myself wondering about a basic thing. Do modern websites store ALL their pages in the frontend ? To illustrate this let me take my project as an example: the goal is to create a website that helps people new to programming learning a language, so it should contain courses and exercises on given languages.
Now, do I really have to hard-code ALL the courses and exercises as components of my front-end ?

My idea was to basically fetch a file from the back-end upon user's request and load that file on the front-end which would serve as the actual course/exercise requested by the user.
I'm asking this because I think it would be better to load the back-end and not front-end, and also it makes for some huge time waste if I have to type and protect every path with an authentificationGuard.

TL;DR: Is it possible to "load" an HTML file (with styling) that would be fetched from back-end storage upon user's request or am I stuck writing HTML on front-end ?

Comment: How is that any different than an http request to load a page?

Comment: Angular and such create the HTML on the client side, using their models and templates. So you don't hardcode all the courses, you put them in a database that you protect with a guard. Then the front end fetches the courses ( usually as a json file ) and creates the actual HTML pages. And yes, what you describe in the TLDR, is the basic web model. But whatever architecture, you'll be writing 'some' HTML, no matter if it's a html template for the frontend or template rendered in the back end, a fully frontend generated site or a fully static backend site.

Comment: "I don't want to code every test page in the  front-end. Let's code them in the back end because it's better".

Comment: "Is it possible to "load" an HTML file (with styling) that would be fetched from back-end storage upon user's request". Well of course it is. This is how ALL, yes I said all, websites work. Might I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the basics of web programming.

Comment: I'm not saying I don't want to code them, it should be obvious enough that I have to write them at some point. And reading your comments there's something I think I've missed. You're saying that my angular project once deployed does not load entirely on user's browser but rather makes call for pages ? If it's that, then my bad, I thought front-end was something that's entirely loaded once browser access it.

Comment: In what is called a "single page app", what you describe is the case. However, the browser still had to load that single page and that single page contains some html. Where do you suppose the browser loaded it from if not the server?

Comment: It looks like I was missing some basic understanding of web apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem quite new to programming based on your question, don't be ashamed of that.  Also, yes, that is how web apps work.  A user/browser sends a request to the "back-end" and then the HTML/JS/CSS is fetched and sent to the user on the "front-end".  The front-end code can be from static files stored on the server, or created dynamically on request with back-end code and sent to the client that way.

For example, you could have the same HTML/CSS structure for every page you are displaying, but dynamically set the content based on what is in the database.  I would recommend some more tutorials to get a feel for the flow of data between the server and client.